# Can we skip/bypass the intermediate layers in multi tier architecture

Tags: .net, architecture, multi-tier

I am working on the project in which we have layered architecture in the following sequence

Web layer (ASP.NET MVC) -> WCF Services -> Business layer -> Data layer (Entity Framework) -> Database (SQL SERVER)

The web layer is hosted in one web application (calling it as web tier) and other layers (WCF, business layer and Data layer) hosted in another web application (calling it as App tier)

All the web requests travel in above sequence.

Now we have a component which is hosted inside windows service and it require to communicate to database, so what is the better way should I directly call the database from windows service by bypassing/ skipping service and data layer or I should use the below flow

Windows Service -> WCF Services -> Business layer -> Data layer (Entity Framework) -> Database

Which one is the better architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't any extensive provisioning required for the windows service to communicate to the data layer then I don't see why you wouldn't. Plus it'll keep your architecture consistent (code exceptions can impede maintainability).

However, if interfacing the windows service to the data layer requires a significant amount of overhead and/or refactoring, then the answer depends on how extensive the windows service communication is with the data layer (are there only a few calls required; how likely will it be expanded on to include more calls in the future). I wouldn't go spending hours or days refactoring existing code just for consistencies sake for an exceptional, one-off and/or simple case (remember, EVERY code change should be TESTED).

It's important to weigh the difference between what could be gained now VS what it could cost later.

Comment: Hi Samus, Our windows service is supposed to work based on some push mechanism, i.e. If any trigger will be generated then windows service need to perform some business operations. Other point is that this windows service need not to communicate to database frequently..